# ClassNotFoundException in mvc application

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` in this code when I run it on a server But as a stand alone java file it runs fine.

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import UserJavaBean.UserJavaBean;

public class UserDataBase {

    public int insert() 
    { 
        int flag =0;
        try
        {   
            UserJavaBean user= new UserJavaBean();
            //Statement stmt= null;
            PreparedStatement ps= null;
            //ResultSet rs= null;
            Connection conn;
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Class Loaded");

            conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:****:orcl","hr","hr");
            System.out.println("Connection Established");

            //          stmt= conn.createStatement();
            int emp_id= user.getId();
            String emp_name=user.getName();
            String emp_des=user.getDesignation();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into nanda values(?,?,?)" );
            ps.setString(1,emp_name);
            ps.setInt(2,emp_id);
            ps.setString(3,emp_des);
            ps.executeUpdate();

            flag=1;

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            flag=0;

        }
        System.out.println("flagvalue"+flag);

        return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the stack trace? is your driver jar in your classpath?

Comment: Please update the question with the stacktrace.

Comment: OMG, so many things wrong with this code. If possible, discuss this with somebody who has experience with server side DB access.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided `exception stacktrace`. But I think you should provide the respective jar file of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` in class path as well as inside lib folder. You might have forget to provide the jar file inside lib folder of the project. As you are not getting any error during stand alone run, you have provide the jar file in class path and it is taking the class path jar file. But when you deploy your web application you have to provide the same jar file inside the lib folder. So that after deployment it will take the jar file from lib folder.

In a nutshell, After deployment, the class path jar files are not available for web app.

I think this will resolve your problem. Try it and let me know.